# how do i send FormData to the node server from React js axios post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to send the form data to the node server, the data is showing at the time of request in the network payload but not reaching to the node server.
Request initiator file.

```
let formData = new FormData();

         // formData.append('test', 'hello');
         formData.append('productImage', productImage);
         // console.log(productName);
         formData.append('productName', productName);
         formData.append('productDesc', productDesc);
         formData.append('productPrice', productPrice);
         formData.append('productCategory', productCategory);
         formData.append('productQty', productQty);
         // var options = { content: formData };

         console.log(formData.entries());

         createProduct(formData)
            .then((response) => {
               console.log('server response = ', response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               console.log('Error Occurred ', err);
            });
      }
```

product.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const createProduct = async (formData) => {
   console.log(formData);
   const response = await axios.post('/api/products/', formData);

   return response;
};
```

server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const connectDB = require('./database/db');

const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const categoryRoutes = require('./routes/category');
const productRoutes = require('./routes/products');

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/category', categoryRoutes);
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);

connectDB();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening to port ${port}`));
```

routes/products.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const productsController = require('../controllers/products');
const { authenticateJWT } = require('../middleware/authenticator');

router.post('/', authenticateJWT, productsController.create);
// router.get('/', authenticateJWT, categoryController.readAll);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/products.js

```
const Products = require('../models/Products');

exports.create = async (req, res) => {
   // const { product } = req.file;

   console.log(req.body);

   try {
      // const categoryExists = await Category.findOne({ category });
      // let newProduct = new Products();
      //   newProduct.product_name = ;
      // newProduct = await newProduct.save();
      res.status(200).json({
         successMessage: '  was created',
      });
   } catch (err) {
      console.log('Category create error', err);
      return res.status(500).json({
         errorMessage: 'Please try again later',
      });
   }
};
```

It shows the empty object in the console while printing the `req.body`.

```
GET /api/category/ 304 2935.667 ms - -
[0] {}
[0] POST /api/products/ 200 4.827 ms - 34
```

[image]

see the network payload shows the data.

can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing 
`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }`

To 
`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`

and add the following line

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //this line is already mentioned above
app.use(bodyParser.json());//add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add content type to headers on axios.post.

```js
export const createProduct = (formData) => {
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/products/',
    data: formData,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  });
};
```

Also use `bodyParser.urlencoded()` middleware on server side.

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

You will get data from `req.body`.

Comment: I added both as you suggested but no luck still getting the empty object.

Comment: @ShivShankarPrasad have you got any solution. I am in the same boat now. node side, it is empty I tried log req. the body is empty. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mark. Did you solve your problem?  I have it right now...

Comment: Hi Mustafa, Are you able to solve it ? Facing same issue