# How to send form data from React to the Node JS back end server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to send the FormData from React JS to the backend (express node server) as shown below.

I am seeing the empty value for `req.body.myFormData (expressTest.js)`.
I tried the suggestions from this post too but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

[how do i send FormData to the node server from React js axios post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030961/how-do-i-send-formdata-to-the-node-server-from-react-js-axios-post-request)

reactTest.js module

```
myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append("userName","TestUser")
myFormData.append("files", file) // input type file
export const sendDocument = async (myFormData) => {
  return await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `/sendDocument`,
    data: myFormData,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  });
};
```

expressTest.js

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.myFormData) //giving undefined //tried req.myFormData too
  console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.myFormData.userName))
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/sendMyUserData',
    data: req.body.myFormData,
    headers: {
      apiKey: 'keytoapi',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      
      return res.send(res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('error')
     }
```

After adding the `multer`, recommended by @con-fused and @Kidas, I can read the FormData in the Express router.

Below is the output.

```
console.log(req.body)

[Object: null prototype] {
  files: '[object File]',
  userName: 'TestUser'
}
```

Now I need to send this to my backend Java end point-Am I sending the right body? it is not hitting my endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sendMyUserData", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
        public String uploadMyUserData(@RequestPart(value = "files") final MultipartFile[] multipartFiles, @RequestPart(value = "userName", required = true) String userName ) {
            return myService.storeFiles(multipartFiles, userName));
    }
```

Comment: did you try `console.log(req.body)`, to see what you get ?

Comment: yes, it printed empty {}

Comment: nope. I tried those. I tried JSON.Stringify too, if do not know, please do not mark it as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multer to get the multipart/form-data.

`npm i multer`

```
formdataParser = require('multer')().fields([])
app.use(formdataParser)
```

Updated according to

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/88#issuecomment-173644716 comment

Comment: yes, I already those two in my configuration app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: Looks like its the issue with expressJs. Try going with this help: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/88#issuecomment-173644716

Comment: Thanks, @con-fused, it works now. I just updated the post. I am trying to see how to send the file with metadata to the back end

Comment: I am marking your answw correct but it did not solve actual issue which I posted in new question. Can you please  check  if you can help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941537/not-able-to-send-the-multi-part-form-data-from-react-express-js-to-the-back-end