# Unable to send the multi part form data from React to Express Js correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, form-data

I am trying to upload files using Dropzone and send these files to java back end API from React JS. Here React is sending the document to express back end and adding some keys and then sending the final form data to back end java endpoint. But not able to get the files and request part in the back end side. The express is getting the wrong format of the data Appreciate any help.

UploadMyFiles.jsx

```
const UploadMyFiles = () => {

  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles]= useState(null)
  const [userName,setUserName]=userState('TestUser')

  const handleUserFileUpload = (userSelectedFiles) => {
        setSelectedFiles(userSelectedFiles)  

    const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append('files', selectedFiles)
    formData.append('userName', userName,)
    const { res} = sendDocument(formData) //refer reactTest.js module below

  }

  return (

          <div className='myClass'>Select Bill</div>
          <Dropzone
            accept={'.pdf'}
            onDrop={selectedFiles => handleUserFileUpload (selectedFiles)}
          >
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (<div {...getRootProps()} id='no-padding'>
              <input
                {...getInputProps()}
                type='file'
                id='attachments'
                name='attachments'
                className='myclass'
              />              
            
            </div>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
  )
}
export default UploadMyFiles
```

reactTest.js

```
export const sendDocument = async (myFormData) => {
  return await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `/sendDocument`,
    data: myFormData,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  });
};
```

expressTest.Js module [Node JS]

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) //see **output below, File data is in string format which is causing the wrong format in my axios router call to backend. How do I get actual file instead of this [object File]. I beliver it is because of multer bodyparser
  console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.myFormData.userName))
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/sendMyUserData',
    data: req.body,
    headers: {
      apiKey: 'keytoapi'
      //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      
      return res.send(res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('error')
     }
```

**output of the console.log

```
{"files":"[object File]","userName":"TestUser"}
```

As you see "files" data is in string format which is causing the wrong formData format for 'data' in my Axios router call to backend. How do I get the actual file instead of this [object File]? I believe it is because of multer bodyparser.

My backend Java endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sendMyUserData", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
        public String uploadMyUserData(@RequestPart(value = "files") final MultipartFile[] multipartFiles, @RequestPart(value = "userName", required = true) String userName ) {
            return myService.storeFiles(multipartFiles, userName));
    }
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=utf-8' not supported
```

I tried to set the content type in the expressTest.js module but I am getting all null values in the backend endpoint

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;
```

[image]

full request headers -captured from my request from the browser network tab

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/sendMyUserData
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8
Authorization:mytoken
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83474
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARkOrs
Cookie: Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/sendDocument
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.114 Safari/537.36
------WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARkOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"

TestUser
------WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARkOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Xyz.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: The java backend is irrelevant. Your express.js proxy server already receives the wrong request data - `res.body` appears to be a JSON document even. Please [edit] your question to include the complete frontend code that is related to getting the file from the input element and making the request using axios.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for taking a look at it. I have updated the post and included the code that has the logic to send the formData

Comment: Which `Dropzone` library are you using, [that one](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone)?

Comment: @Bergi, that is correct react-dropzone

Comment: Btw the `setSelectedFiles(userSelectedFiles)` hook is used wrong, appending `selectedFiles` will append the old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [the `append` method of `FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) takes either a string or a single file for the value, and "*if none of these are specified the value is converted to a string*". You are however passing an **array** of files (`selectedFiles`), which gets stringified to `"[object File]"` (if selecting two files at once, it would be `[object File],[object File]` - just what `Array.prototype.toString` and `Object.prototype.toString` do).

You will need to do

```
const UploadMyFiles = () => {
  const [userName,setUserName] = userState('TestUser')
  const handleUserFileUpload = (selectedFiles) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    for (const file of selectedFiles)
      formData.append('files', file)
    formData.append('userName', userName)
    sendDocument(formData).catch(…)
  }

  return (
    <div className='myClass'>Select Bill</div>
      <Dropzone
        accept={'.pdf'}
        onDrop={handleUserFileUpload}
      >…</Dropzone>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Browser network tab
[image]

Comment: I just did a few hours ago. I tried with formData.append("files[], selectedFiles[0]) and tried sending only one file for now. I can still see the ouput as [Object: null prototype] { folderName: 'TestUser'}

Comment: adding files[] , shows me the file name in the network heders tab  and the file is being sent as binary, file (binary), but does not show anything else and my backend fails to read, says multipart exception and read time out

Comment: @mark Now that means your frontend is finally working, sending the files correctly, and your backend needs fixing. Please accept this answer about the frontend part, then update [the question about the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65928892/1048572) with the new information and we can discuss how to use multer correctly there.

Comment: I am not sure if it is working but the console.log(req.body.files) still shows [object null prototype] {userName:' TestUser'} where as in the browser network tab it is a file (binary) for a single file . Thanks for checking but I will surely accept once it is working . The backend is alredy working when I tested from postman, I don't think any issue with backend

Comment: added a screenshot of my network tab. Is this expected, or missing anything at the express side?

Comment: added another question for backend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984754/failed-to-parse-multipart-servlet-request-from-express-js-server-to-backend-java

Comment: The request looks good to me (although the pdf file you uploaded appears to be empty?). Do some debugging at the express side how this request is different from the postman one that you say is working.

Comment: @mark then where's its content in the browser network tab? Did your screenshot just not capture it?

Comment: sorry, you mean content-type?

Comment: No, I mean the actual binary contents.

Comment: Ok. It does not show anything. I have updated post with what I can see in the request

Comment: And yet its says `Content-Length: 83474`. So either you're looking at only the headers, or something causes your browser to abort the request

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  I will check