# Failed to parse multipart servlet request from express js server to backend java endpoint

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

This is an extension to an issue with the front end(react->express file upload). The back end API endpoint works fine from Postman but fails from the front end side

[Unable to send the multi part form data from React to Express Js correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941537/unable-to-send-the-multi-part-form-data-from-react-to-express-js-correctly/65983736?noredirect=1#comment116662720_65983736)

Any thoughts on this?

Browser network tab - Headers

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/sendMyUserData
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8
Authorization:mytoken
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83474
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARkOrs
Cookie: Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/sendDocument
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.114 Safari/537.36
------WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARkOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"

TestUser
------WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARkOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Xyz.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryvooZbILex2ARJOrs--
```

my spring boot API endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sendMyUserData", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public String uploadMyUserData(@RequestPart(value = "files") final MultipartFile[] multipartFiles, @RequestPart(value = "userName") String userName ) {
return myService.storeFiles(multipartFiles, userName));
```

Error at the back end API endpoint

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException]
```

Comment: In your previous question there was some node.js server code (express.js). Are you no longer using that and contacting your java spring endpoint directly?

Comment: still using the same, refer expressTest.Js module [Node JS]

 in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941537/unable-to-send-the-multi-part-form-data-from-react-to-express-js-correctly/65983736?noredirect=1#comment116664398_65983736

Comment: Please make each question self-contained. If you meant to provide additional information to an existing question, please edit that one instead of asking a new one. And if your problem is with an express server, post its code, not that of the irrelevant java spring server.

Comment: I think I tried the same. I created two questions. This one, I am not sure where the problem is that's why I added a reference to front-end issue as well.