# How to destructure File object

Tags: javascript

I have an in request with the 'body' parameter. I got the below body object when I did the `console.log(req.body)`. I want to destructure or consume the File for further processing/upload.

the request is formed with below

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", file) //file is of type File, and will be attached from browser
```

How do I get the filename and buffer of the file from the below object?

```
 body: [Object: null prototype] {
    files: '[object File]',
    userName: 'TestUser'
  },
```

I tried

```
console.log(req.body.files)
```

out put

```
[object File]
```

How to destructure this File further to get details about it

Comment: The log suggests that you got sent the string `'[object File]'`, not an actual file. Ensure that `file` in your client code really is a `File` instance, and didn't get stringified somewhere along the way.

Comment: Yes, it is a File instance. The reason you see this format is because of the body-parser, I am using the multer to get the form data in the to react axis router. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928892/how-to-send-form-data-from-react-to-the-node-js-back-end-server/65929018?noredirect=1#comment116567610_65929018

Comment: Yes, you have to use multer to parse the body, but still it looks like you're sending just `files=[object%20File]&userName=TestUser` in the body. Please post the complete code.

Comment: <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' action='submitFormT'> 
    <input type='file' name='files[]' multiple />
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: adding the formData.append(files[0])

Comment: I debugged the chrome dev tools, the file shows size, name attributes before adding to formData.It confirms that the file is of type File and not string

Comment: Further for your info, I am looking for some ideas on my actual issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941537/not-able-to-send-the-multi-part-form-data-from-react-express-js-to-the-back-end

Comment: Does it work if you submit that form without any javascript in the page?

Comment: @Bergi, I have updated my post to show I am sending the files to express https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941537/not-able-to-send-the-multi-part-form-data-from-react-express-js-to-the-back-end

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the file with the file reader

```js
reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsBinaryString(req.body.files);

reader.onloadend = function(){
    console.log(reader.result);
}
```

Comment: where? and then do what? No, there is no `FileReader` in node.js

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant you are trying to do this in a browser. I suggest you use a library like multer for this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

You didn't need to downvote so furiously :p ;-)

Comment: @yes, I am doing the same but the formData is coming incorrectly to express server. see my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941537/not-able-to-send-the-multi-part-form-data-from-react-express-js-to-the-back-end